# JFrame setComponentZOrder() changes size of the objects

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm trying to write an undecorated JFrame. I'm trying to put my button over my background label. However setting the button's Z order causes the button streches to size of jframe and neither setBounds() nor setSize() changes the situation. Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame();
        mainFrame.setBounds(0, 112, 100, 50);
        mainFrame.setLayout(null);
        mainFrame.setUndecorated(true);

        JLabel lblBackground = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(JFrame.class.getResource("/res/green.png")));
        lblBackground.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 50);

        JButton btnStart = new JButton("");
        btnStart.setBounds(5, 15, 10, 15);

        mainFrame.add(lblBackground);
        mainFrame.add(btnStart);
        mainFrame.setComponentZOrder(btnStart, 0); 
        mainFrame.setComponentZOrder(btnStart, 1); 


        mainFrame.setVisible(true);

    }   
}
```

Thanks for replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a JLayeredPane for this.

You will need to create a new JLayeredPane:
`JLayeredPane layered = new JLayeredPane();`

Set your JFrame to use this as a content pane:
`mainFrame.setContentPane(layered);`

And add your components, in this format:
`layered.add(Component c, int layerNumber);`

Hope that works for you!

[More on JLayeredPanes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayeredPane.html)

Answer (score 0):

Don't play with null layouts. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers

Add the button to the label. For example:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel(...);
label.setLayout( new FlowLayout() );
JButton button = new JButton(...);
label.add( button );
frame.add(label);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Now the frame should be the same size as your image. The button should be centered on the top of the image. If you want the button positioned somewhere else then use a different layout manager.